# Multiple threads can move the same file using ATOMIC_MOVE on Windows

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, file-io

I have multithreaded application. My app have Spring scheduler, that starts multiple threads which process file from specific location. I get file to process by calling  `Files.newDirectoryStream(taskFolder, filter)` and iterate over result. I have to ensure that only one thread take files to process. I try to rename file using `ATOMIC_MOVE` to mark that it's being processed by some thread. I expect other threads to not be able to rename this file (MoveFileException should be thrown) which results in file not being processed by those threads (logic in catch block of `MoveFileException` ends the process).

```
try {
    Files.move(source, target, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new MoveFileException("An error occurred while moving the file from: " + source.toString() + " to: " + target.toString(), e);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Still 2 or more threads can rename my file without any exception. So how can I ensure that file will be taken only by one thread.

***EDIT***

I supply more code to understand what I want to do.

**Import.java**

```
for (Path path : filesToProcessPath) {
    final FileToProcessRepresentation fileToProcessRepresentation = new FileToProcessRepresentation(path.toString());

    try {
        fileRepository.moveFileToPendingState(fileToProcessRepresentation);
    } catch (MoveFileException e) {
        LOGGER.debug("File [" + fileToProcessRepresentation.getUri() + "] could be process by another thread", e);
        continue;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        continue;
    }

    //logic

}
```

**FileRespository.java**

```
public void moveFileToPendingState(final FileToProcessRepresentation fileToMove) throws MoveFileException {
    moveFiles(fileToMove, fileToMove.getPendingUri());
    fileToMove.toPending();
}

private void moveFiles(final FileToProcessRepresentation s, final String uri) throws MoveFileException {
    Path sourceFile = Paths.get(s.getUri());
    Path destinationFile = Paths.get(uri);
    moveFiles(sourceFile, destinationFile);
}

private void moveFiles(final Path source, final Path target) throws MoveFileException {
    try {
        Files.move(source, target, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new MoveFileException("An error occurred while moving the file from: " + source.toString() + " to: " + target.toString(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it possible for you to work with `FileChannel`s instead, and use its `lock()` functionality?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes. I can completely change approach. What I need is that it will work.

Comment: *But it doesn't work*  That's not a useful description.  *What* happens?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Still 2 or more threads can rename my file without any exception.

Comment: @J.Marciniak And what happens to the file?

Comment: @AndrewHenle 2 or more thread process file. It's XML, I read information from that file and execute some actions. If 2 or more threads do this I have repeated information in my system

Comment: @J.Marciniak You're still not being clear about what happens to the actual file on disk.

Comment: @AndrewHenle file has new name that's all

Comment: Which name? Old one, new one or both? If there are different "new ones", which one wins? Are contents the same?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov all threads change only name to old_one.ext_pending. That's all. So my file has the same content and name: old_one.ext_pending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem just add `synchronized` to `moveFileToPendingState` method.

Comment: it is still strange that multiple threads can do the atomic move in parallel, it should be synchronized in my opinion itself!